# How to identify correct readings in scripture in case of ambiguity?

Tags: scripture

How to identify actual reading in scripture when the reading of the verse is ambiguous which occurs because of the way sandhi can be resolved?

For eg: While all others take the Chandogya Upanishad verse as 'tat tvam asi', Madhvacharya makes it 'atat tvam asi'. This is because of the compound word that can be split differently.

Also, when can there can be double meanings in the scriptures meaning scriptural verse itself is spoken to give two valid meanings?

Comment: learning from an acharya with humility definitely works in clearing doubts

Comment: What is "actual reading"? "reading of the verse is ambiguous" one can look at other scriptures or view it from the line of sanatan dharma other than that one cannot do anything else.